Angular RxJS - make http call once
I have a service where i call a 3part service for get logged user
export class UserService {
  //Logged User Object
  private _user: User;

  getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this._user
      ? of({ ...this._user })
      : this.userProvider.getUser().pipe(
        share(),
      tap((usr) => (this._user = usr)));

      //userProvider is a service where inside I get the actual http call
  }
}

in my App's HomePage there are many component who consume the observable getCurrentUser(),
The idea is call the User once and then alwais return the private object.
But in network inspector I got

At least 3 different components are calling simultaneously the service causing the http call being triggered at every call (UserDataDaCookie is the actual endpoint mapped by my userProvider)
How can i ensure only the first caller do this and then others subsequently wait for completion?
I also tried with exhaustMap
export class UserService {
  //Logged User Object
  private _user: User;

  getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
  
     return this._user
            ? of({
                  ...this._user
              })
            : of(this._user).pipe(
                  exhaustMap(() =>
                      this.userPrv.getUser().pipe(
                          share(),
                             tap((usr) => (this._user = usr))
                      )))
  }
}

What am I wrong?
Thanks

Well, even if you are sharing the observable with share(), each time someone calls getCurrentUser() it gets a new copy of the observable object, that will be shared with the caller only. You should create the observable outside of the function, maybe on ngOnInit or implement some kind of guard

We can use an AsyncSubject to cache the result, below is the pattern obtained from Reactive Programming with rxjs - Sergei Mansilla : 47, here we create a method which contains a AsyncSubject which is initially undefined, then we create a property which we can subscribe to all our observers const currentUser = getCurrentUser();, when we subscribe to this property, we make the API call (code inside the new Observable((observer: any) => {...})) ( the extra code is to mock an API call natively using fetch ), we use from to convert the promise from from to an observable, then we set the async subject to a value by passing it into the subscribe of the API call. Finally we call subject.subscribe(observer) to notify all the observers after the async subject value is set.
function getCurrentUser() {
  return new Observable((observer: any) => {
    if (!subject) {
      subject = new AsyncSubject();
      console.log('api');
      from(
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((response) =>
          response.json()
        )
      )
        .pipe(tap((usr: any) => (_user = usr)))
        .subscribe(subject);
    }
    return subject.subscribe(observer);
  });
}

Full Code:
import './style.css';

import { tap, from, delay, AsyncSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

let _user: any;
let subject: any;
const currentUser = getCurrentUser();

function getCurrentUser() {
  return new Observable((observer: any) => {
    if (!subject) {
      subject = new AsyncSubject();
      console.log('api');
      from(
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((response) =>
          response.json()
        )
      )
        .pipe(tap((usr: any) => (_user = usr)))
        .subscribe(subject);
    }
    return subject.subscribe(observer);
  });
}
currentUser.subscribe({
  next: (result: any) => {
    console.log('Result 1:', result);
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    console.log('ERROR', error);
  },
});
// Will receive the result immediately because it's cached
setTimeout(function () {
  currentUser.subscribe({
    next: (result: any) => {
      console.log('Result 2:', result);
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      console.log('ERROR', error);
    },
  });
}, 5000);

Stackblitz Demo
